# Recent Edits should show better data for tag edits

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits, 10k-tools

The [recent edits](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/recent-edits) page is not terribly useful for posts where the only change was a tag edit. For posts where the tags were edited, I propose that the resulting tags be shown.

Otherwise I would have to question the usefulness of showing posts where only the tags were changed, without actually showing the tags.

Comment: Recurring problem. Search for words like manual retagging and bumping. The SE team never seems very motivated to deal with it. :)